# C# DataAccess Update, Insert, Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am a newborn programmer who is currently looking into the Insert, Update and Delete functions in ASP.NET C#. Now I got a little support from a friend who was friendly enough to write a DataAccess for me (I guess it's a BLL) before he left for work.

I am used to using Datasets and gridviews which is all pretty straight forward, so this way of working with data is very very difficult to me.

Now, I have lots of codes in the DataAccess, but I guess this is the one I have to concentrate about:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used for Create/Update/Delete etc.
/// </summary>
public void Execute(string query)
{
    SqlCommand comm = GetSqlCommand(query);

    _conn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _conn.Close();
}
```

And I am wondering:

1. How do I use an Insert, Update And Delete from a DataAccess file
2. What am I supposed to put into my .aspx page?

I hope my questions isn't too "large" an area to explain if you know what I mean :)
Any help is more than appreciated guys!

Regards,
Mike

Comment: `BLL` - Business Logic Layer. This is not the same as a `DAL` - Data Access Layer.

Comment: Oh, I don't remember exactly what he called it :) but its a DataAccess.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aaa hi mike,lets review on n-tier architecture :

DB <-> DAL <-> BLL <-> PL

the sample code you write in your question is one part of DAL layer, not BLL layer

about first question :

it depend on your architecture . if you have 3-tier approach , so in your aspx file just write something like this :

```
new DAL().Execute("INSERT INTO TABLE TABLENAME VALUES (...)");
```

but if you have 4-tier approach ,so you just put this(last mentioned code) code in your BLL classes and in your aspx file call a method from BLL classes.

but i have another offer for you my friend , use newer technique such as LinQ or Entity Framework to create your DLL layer and then create a BLL layer.

if you need more help comment me to edit my reply or post another answer for more details.

thanks , Ali

Comment: Hey Ali! Thank you for your very detailed reply! I have to admit that I'm not experienced enough to write my own DAL as in the sample code I gave. I have heard about LinQ and I am just not experienced enough to write it myself, that's why my friend helped me :)

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. But this was a good and well educational reply which helped me a lot!:)

Comment: your welcome dude ;-) you can account on me for more help by mail me to me@ali-foroughi.net . good luck , waiting for your emails

Answer (score 0):

To use your Execute function you have to write the sql statements that should be executed. Your data access layer seems to work like that. But that isn't what I would expect from a DAL (data access layer), it should completely incapsulate the data access, so that the BLL (business logic layer) must not know how the database works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create methods in `DataAccess.cs` file to `insert`, `update` and `detele`. Then you can use those method inside your `.aspx` files.

Have a look at these article about [Creating a Data Access Layer in ASP.Net applications for inserting,selecting,deleting and updating data](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/01/23/ffff.aspx) and [Creating a Data Access Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx) which will give you a proper understand about the process.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a different approach to the one you are using, I thought it might still be a possible answer.

You could look into using Linq (to SQl).

Scott Guthrie has a series of articles to get you started with.

I'll link to article 8, which contains links to the previous parts.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx

You should get what you need from parts 1 - 4.

Basically LINQ will enable you to make SQLquery like queries to the database, either like this:

```
MyDatabaseContext db = new MyDatabaseContext();

var res = from item in db.Table
where item.Column == 2
select item;
//or using Lambda expressions
var res2= db.Table.Where(x => x.Column == 1);
```

This should enable you to expand your different methods yourself and get your started on Linq, which is very neat. :)

I hope this helps.